# Is it possible to have a latex algorithm inside an R markdown file?

Tags: algorithm2e, knitr, rstudio

I'm trying to use the following inside an R Markdown file (.Rmd):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e} 
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

but it always giving me this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Any idea how I can get this working ?

Answer (score 1):

You mixed several things here.

1. You talk about `Rmd` and RMarkdowd, while this file is `rnw` and written in R LaTeX.
2. You use `Sweave` syntax, but mark your questions as `knitr`.

Let us assume that you indeed want `knitr`.  Then delete `Sweave` specific options.

Here is the file `tmp.rnw`, where I added an arbitrary R chunk

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e} 
\begin{document}

<<>>=
summary(cars)
@ 

\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

I run it through `knitr` and `pdflatex` and got

[image]